# PL/SQL how can ı fixed process flag id=4 wrong printing and how can I error message

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Create table

```
create table curexample_test (id number, x number, y number, result number, process_flag varchar2(1), error_message varchar2(400))

insert into curexample_test
select 1, 20,4,null,null,null from dual
union
select 2, 15,3,null,null,null from dual
union
select 3, 36,9,null,null,null from dual
union
select 4, 7,0,null,null,null from dual
union
select 5, 105,15,null,null,null from dual

select * from curexample_test
```

Create function

```
create or replace function divider(n1 in number, n2 in number)    
        return number    
            is     
            pragma autonomous_transaction;
            n3 number;    
         begin    
             
            if n2 = 0 then
               n3 :=null; 

                 update curexample_test set process_flag = 'E' where n3 = null ;
              
            else
                n3 :=n1 / n2; 
                 update curexample_test set process_flag = 'S' where n3 !=0 ;
        end if;
            COMMIT;
    return n3;    
        end;
```

Call function

```
select id,x,y , divider(x,y) as result,process_flag,error_message from curexample_test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We rarely perform DML within a function; use a procedure, if you have to do that.

As of your code:

- `WHERE` clauses in `UPDATE` statements have to be fixed
- if you want to store the `RESULT`, fix the `SET` clause as well
- if you're comparing something to `NULL`, then it isnt e.g. `where n3 = null` but `where n3 IS NULL`

---

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION divider (n1 IN NUMBER, n2 IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  5
  6     n3  NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8     IF n2 = 0
  9     THEN
 10        n3 := NULL;
 11
 12        UPDATE curexample_test
 13           SET result = n3, process_flag = 'E'
 14         --WHERE n3 = NULL;
 15         WHERE     x = n1
 16               AND y = n2;
 17     ELSE
 18        n3 := n1 / n2;
 19
 20        UPDATE curexample_test
 21           SET result = n3, process_flag = 'S'
 22         -- WHERE n3 != 0;
 23         WHERE     x = n1
 24               AND y = n2;
 25     END IF;
 26
 27     COMMIT;
 28     RETURN n3;
 29  END;
 30  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT id,
  2         x,
  3         y,
  4         divider (x, y) AS result,
  5         process_flag,
  6         error_message
  7    FROM curexample_test;

        ID          X          Y     RESULT PROCESS_FLAG    ERROR_MESSAGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- --------------------
         1         20          4          5
         2         15          3          5
         3         36          9          4
         4          7          0
         5        105         15          7
```

Table contents is then

```
SQL> select * from curexample_test;

        ID          X          Y     RESULT PROCESS_FLAG    ERROR_MESSAGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- --------------------
         1         20          4          5 S
         2         15          3          5 S
         3         36          9          4 S
         4          7          0            E
         5        105         15          7 S

SQL>
```

Comment: Also how ı can add error message for id=4

Comment: In unsuccessful cases, the error message should be printed in the error_message field in the table.

Comment: Add it into the UPDATE statement, its SET clause - just like RESULT or PROCESS_FLAG. No difference.

Comment: thanks a lot , I guessed  catch exception

Comment: You aren't "catching" anything as IF prevents it to.